# Issue with aptitude apt-get install

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

When attempting to install using apt-get in ubuntu 12.04 I get the following error:

Segmentation faultsts... 0%

Alternatively the error sometimes presents as:

sts... 0%

Command launched:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

This issue is impacting installation of anything utilising apt-get

Answer (score 0):

So the solution turned out to be an issue with apt-get cache files. It was resolved by removal of files:

pkgcache.bin
srcpkgcache.bin

under directory
    /var/cache/apt

After this the installation process proceeded correctly.
I also ran
    sudo aptitude update

to ensure they were replaced :)